# Vue $route.push not working when called from method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm building a search bar for my app with `vue-bootstrap-typeahead` autocomplete lib, if your not familiar with it, when you click a suggested result it triggers the `@hit` event, passing the result data to the method.

```
<vue-bootstrap-typeahead
    ...
    @hit="goToResult"
    ...
/>
```

Then I have the `goToResult` method

```
    methods: {
        goToResult(result) {
                this.$router.push({name: 'market', params: {marketId: result.id}});
        },
        ...
     }
```

When I do search from a non-market route it works fine, redirecting the user to the desired `/market/:marketId` route, but when it's done from a "market" route it just changes the URL but doesn't redirects to the new market, it even triggers the "duplicated route" error if I click the same result twice, but still not redirecting.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the note at the bottom of the `router.push` section: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html

> Note: If the destination is the same as the current route and only params are changing (e.g. going from one profile to another /users/1 -> /users/2), you will have to use beforeRouteUpdate to react to changes (e.g. fetching the user information).

...and here is how to use `beforeRouteUpdate`:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you!